# "Einer von ihnen lachte." Why "Einer"?

Tags: declension

I'm familiar with the basics: case, gender, declensions, etc.

The above sentence refers to one of two males, if that helps.

My understanding (might be wrong):
- "One of them laughed" so "One" is the subject, i.e. Nominative. "Ein von ihnen" just *sounds* wrong to my ears, but I don't know why.

Isn't the nominative of male nouns simply "ein"?

Thanks ahead.

Paulo

**Update:**
Thanks to Hubert. It seems I was not as familiar with the basics as I thought. Here is some info on indefinite article declension (which I just went and read up on myself) for anyone else seeking it: https://deutsch.lingolia.com/en/grammar/pronouns/indefinite-pronouns

Comment: No, the nominative of a male noun is whatever the reading of that noun is. *ein* is the nominative singular of the *indefinite article*. Here, *einer* is neither a noun nor an article. It's an indefinite pronoun, like "some" or "many".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is neither an article nor a numeral, it is an indefinite pronoun:

- **masculine** (men, spoons)

  > Vor der Tür standen zwei Männer. **Einer** von ihnen lachte.
  >   Two men were standing in front of the door. One of them laughed.
  >
  > In der Lade lagen zwei Löffel. **Einer** von ihnen war aus Holz.
  >   There were two spoons in the drawer. One of them was made of wood.
- **feminine** (women, forks)

  > Vor der Tür standen zwei Frauen. **Eine** von ihnen lachte.
  >   Two women were standing in front of the door. One of them laughed.
  >
  > In der Lade lagen zwei Gabeln. **Eine** von ihnen war aus Holz.
  >   There were two forks in the drawer. One of them was made of wood.
- **neuter** (children, knives)

  > Vor der Tür standen zwei Kinder. **Eines** von ihnen lachte.
  >   Two children were standing in front of the door. One of them laughed.
  >
  > In der Lade lagen zwei Messer. **Eines** von ihnen war aus Holz.
  >   There were two knives in the drawer. One of them was made of wood.

This is different from the usage as numeral or article:

- **masculine**

  > Ein Mann lachte. = One man laughed.
  >   Ein Löffel liegt in der Lade. = There is one spoon in the drawer.
- **feminine**

  > Eine Frau lachte. = One woman laughed.
  >   Eine Gabel liegt in der Lade. = There is one fork in the drawer.
- **neuter**

  > Ein Kind lachte. = One child laughed.
  >   Ein Messer liegt in der Lade. = There is one knife in the drawer.

Comment: Besser wäre ein Beispiel mit "Eine von ihnen (zwei Personen) lachte", und "Eines von ihnen (den Mitgliedern) lachte", um nicht den falschen Eindruck zu verstärken dass es auf das Geschlecht der Person statt des Wortes ankäme.

Comment: Übrigens, *Lade* ist in meinen Teil unseres Sprachraums ungewöhnlich, hier heißt das *Schublade* Ich wurde (dunkel, ich musste googeln) an die Bundeslade erinner.

Comment: @CarstenS: Ich verstehe bis heute nicht, warum dieser biblische Transportbehälter Bundes*lade* heißt, wenn er doch in Wahrheit eine Truhe ist.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast. weil das die [(veraltende) Bedeutung von *Lade*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Lade) ist, weshalb. Deshalb spezifizieren ja einige genauer, wenn sie von *Schub*laden reden. (Natürlich benutzen die meisten davon nie tatsächlich das Wort *Lade*.)

Comment: Ich sollte meine Kommentare gewissenhafter zur Korrektur lesen.

Answer (score 2):

I would call it the "der" form of "Ein."

If it were a noun modifier, the sentence might be *Ein* Mann lachte."

But it's a "standalone" (masculine) pronoun, with "von ihnen" as a modifier. That's why it needs to take the "er" form, which is "Einer."